# When to involve electron mass in energy calculation of beta decay

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radioactivity

I would just like to apologise for the horrible images because I have no idea to format the subscripts of the elements. **Why is that we do not have to account for the weight of the electron in beta minus emission?** Some of the solutions for other similar questions involve the weight of the electron. Is there a rule regarding when to account for it that I am not aware of? For reference, this is from the *Giancoli Physics 6th Edition Textbook*.

> (II) The isotope $^{218}_{84}\rm Po$ can decay by either $\alpha$ or $\beta^-$ emission. What is the energy release in each case? The mass of $^{218}_{84}\rm Po$ is $218.008965\ \rm u$.

**Answer:**
For beta decay we have $^{218}_{84}\mathrm{Po} \rightarrow^{218}_{85}\mathrm{At}+^0_{-1}\mathrm{e}$ The $Q$ value is
\begin{align}
\\Q&=[m(^{218}_{84}\mathrm{Po})-m(^{218}_{85}\mathrm{At})]c^2
\\&=[(218.008965\mathrm{u}-(218.00868\mathrm{u})]c^2(931.5\mathrm{MeV/u}c^2)=0.27\mathrm{MeV}
\end{align}

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Please don't post formulae as pictures or plain text, but use MathJax instead. MathJax is easy for people on all devices to read, and can show up clearer on different screen sizes and resolutions. I've edited it here as an example. Look at [this Math SE meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick tutorial.

Comment: Duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/378900/104696

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you would expect, all masses need to be accounted for - always.

Here is what is causing the confusion: The atomic masses cited include the mass of the electrons in the neutral atom.  So, we have that $m(^{218}_{84}\mathrm{Po})$ includes 218 nucleons and 84 electrons while $m(^{218}_{85}\mathrm{As})$ includes the mass for one extra electron.

In the decay $^{218}_{84}\mathrm{Po} \longrightarrow ^{218}_{85}\mathrm{As} + e^- + Q$ we refer to the nucleus that is decaying.  But in the atomic mass difference the mass of the emitted electron is already included.

Hence, for this decay, the difference in the atomic masses is indeed the Q-value (ie kinetic energy) of the emitted electron + anti-neutrino.

I hope this helps.

Sources: See here for the latest [atomic masses](http://cms.iopscience.org/085e4ab8-0d63-11e7-9a47-19ee90157113/030003_Table1.pdf?guest=true)

Comment: I moved the charge numbers to the usual side for you. And while I was at it I typeset the atomic symbols in an upright face.

Comment: Thanks @dmckee My $\TeX$ knowledge is a bit rusty at times.  It has been 25 years.

Comment: @Michael Momayezi nice answer but could you please tell me why don't we take into account the mass of the neutrino emitted?