# $\beta^-$ and $\beta^+$ $Q$ value issue

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, radioactivity, binding-energy

It's unclear to me why the following doesn't work when I calculate the $Q$ value for $\beta^-$ and $\beta^+$ decay. If we start with a parent nucleus $P_z$ with $Z$ electrons decaying through $\beta^-$ producing a daughter nucleus $D_{z+1}$ with $Z+1$ electrons:

$$Q = (P_z + Z*m_e) - (D_{Z+1} + (Z+1)*m_e + m_e).$$

Assuming that the Daughter is charge neutral and $m_e$ is the mass of an electron I find:

$$Q = P_z - D_{Z+1} -2m_e$$

I was expecting to get: 
$$Q = P_z - D_{Z+1}$$

For $\beta^+$ decay I have a similar problem where I get:
$$Q = P_z - D_{Z-1}$$ 
when I expect to get 
$$Q = P_z - D_{Z-1} -2m_e$$

Can someone please point out where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to involve electron mass in energy calculation of beta decay](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/420982/)

Comment: Not really in my case $P_Z$ and $D_Z$ are atomic nuclei (I shall update my question to reflect this). Hence I don't think the electrons are included in this. I guess my question is more related to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#Energy_release. Why do we need to convert from the mass of the nucleus to atomic masses..

Comment: But you have electrons included in your calculations. Compare what is in that question with yours - it shows how to include the creation of the relevant beta.

Comment: Yeah but the question suggests that I have double-counted electrons and I don't think I have.

Comment: If you prefer, try https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186897/, or search for 'beta decay q value' and find other Q/A.

Answer (score -1):

When you calculate Q values of nuclear reactions you should use the nuclear masses of the nuclei involved. The tables of masses available to us are tables of *neutral atomic masses*.

Therefore, to get the nuclear mass you should *subtract* the electron masses from the tabulated atomic masses. In your case for $\beta^-$ decay you should have
$$Q = (P_Z - Z*m_e) - (D_{Z+1} - (Z+1)*m_e + m_e),$$ 
where $P_Z$ and $D_{Z+1}$ will be the tabulated neutral atomic masses.  I think you'll get what you expected, both in this case and the $\beta^+$ case.

You should also try it for the electron capture and alpha decay cases.

Comment: This is sound advice for decays of bare nuclei. But for heavy nuclei, the electron binding energies are also significant.