What is the atomic mass defect (or nuclear binding energy) of Iron-56 (Fe-56)?
It seems a simple enough calculation, but I keep getting 478.972467.... MeV.
Yet, Wikipedia insists on 492.275 MeV, and other sites give very similar numbers to Wikipedia's, not mine....
What am I missing?
What am I miscalculating?
P.S.:  I didn't include the electrons....I swear I was going to before making this post, when I was initially confused... but then several sites said don't bother, nuclear physicists don't usually include them... Obviously, those websites lied...
I now get 492.2587......

Google ‘Atomic Mass Evaluation’ - the 2020 is the latest issue with the currently accepted atomic masses.

Kurt. $\approx$ 492.27 MeV is correct but it's hard to tell what you're missing if we cannot see the calculation.

What's 26 × 511 keV?

@josephh Kurt needs to ask about how to calculate mass defect, and the concepts underlying the calculation, without turning this into an off-topic "check my work" question.

I have used the most precise data that I can get, and even summing the ionisation potentials of the iron atom, all NIST values, and my result is 492.225 MeV; I think Wiki's data needs updating. The ANL figure (what Jon suggested) is 492.260 MeV. (I get that value if I ignore the ionisation potentials.)

Mass defect = $Z\times M_{\rm p} + (A-Z)\times M_{\rm p}+ Z\times M_{\rm e}- M_{\rm A,Z}$ where $M_{\rm A,Z}$ is the mass of an atom.

@Farcher minor quibbles: you missed writing $M_n$ for the 2nd term and it is generally a better idea to use $M_{\text{H}}$ and $Z\times13.6e$V instead; of course, if you use the $13.6e$V, then you should also sum all the ionisation potentials of the final atom.

Mr. (Or Ms.) Naturally Inconsistent is correct, I believe... I now calculate about 492.6 .....

@PM2Ring I suppose that makes sense.

Look very carefully at what masses you think you're adding, and what tabulated masses you are really adding.
Most tables of isotope masses include the orbital electrons.  If you are using the mass of a neutron, a hydrogen atom (with its one orbital electron) and an atom of Fe-56 (with its 26 orbital electrons) then everything should work out.
But if you use the mass of a proton (no orbital electron) then you'll be off by 26 electron masses.
Hence the useful comments of @PM 2Ring and @Farcher
See also  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308631
